# Hibernate : Is it possible to "save cascade" only on test?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to know if it was possible to save cascade my Entities but only when i was running my tests ?

I want to be able to save cascade but only when i run my tests. For testing my dao it will save me a lot of time if i could just save cascade an entity and not getting an error because sub-entities aren't saved yet.

```
@Test
public void addGetEntityTests(){

    Entity entity1 = ...;
    Entity entity2 = ...; //same as entity1

    getDao().addEntity(entity1);
    assertEquals(entity1, entity2);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot perform what you want to achieve without modifying the entity declaration or the query you are testing.
And you should not do it because in this case, your test doesn't perform the same logic than your implementation while a test should check the implementation works as expected.
If you need to have a context when your test start, you should create this context before in the `@Before` method of your class.
You can inject data in your database via your own services (if tested) or SQL with tools as DBunit.

---

**Edit: example with DBunit**

You explain in your comment that setting all data in your object is tedious. So, I suppose you have multiples rows and relationships to set to create your context.
In this case, you may use DBunit and proceed in two steps :

- writing each line in your dataset will be also tedious. Another way to do is creating dynamically your dataset from queries on a exiting database which contains data you want to retrieve. 
  This step will be played once to create the dataset you want to use in your unit tests.
- use this generated dataset before your test starts

I used examples from http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html that I slightly adapted.

For the first step (generating your dataset) :

```
public class DatabaseExportSample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // database connection
        Class driverClass = Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hsqldb:sample", "sa", "");
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

        // partial database export
        QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
        partialDataSet.addTable("FOO", "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL='VALUE'");
        partialDataSet.addTable("BAR");
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("partial.xml"));

        // full database export
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));

        // dependent tables database export: export table X and all tables that
        // have a PK which is a FK on X, in the right order for insertion
        String[] depTableNames = 
          TablesDependencyHelper.getAllDependentTables( connection, "X" );
        IDataSet depDataset = connection.createDataSet( depTableNames );
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(depDataSet, new FileOutputStream("dataset.xml"));                      
    }
}
```

It will generate a xml file (here is a sample) :

```
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "dataset.dtd">
<dataset>
    <table name="TEST_TABLE">
        <column>COL0</column>
        <column>COL1</column>
        <column>COL2</column>
        <row>
            <value>row 0 col 0</value>
            <value>row 0 col 1</value>
            <value>row 0 col 2</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <null/>
            <value>row 1 col 1</value>
            <null/>
        </row>
    </table>
    <table name="SECOND_TABLE">
        <column>COLUMN0</column>
        <column>COLUMN1</column>
        <row>
            <value>row 0 col 0</value>
            <value>row 0 col 1</value>
        </row>
    </table>
    <table name='EMPTY_TABLE'>
        <column>COLUMN0</column>
        <column>COLUMN1</column>
    </table>
</dataset>
```

For the second step (injecting this dataset in your test database) :

```
public class SampleTest {

  @Before
  protected void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super.setUp();

    // initialize your database connection here
    IDatabaseConnection connection = null;
    // ...

    // initialize your dataset here
    IDataSet dataSet = null;
    // ...

    try1
    {
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, "dataset.xml");
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.close();
    }
  }
  ...
  // when your test method starts you have the required data in your test database
  @Test
  public void addGetEntityTests(){
    Entity entity1 = ...;
    getDao().addEntity(entity1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but in the application i just want to test the "add" method. In my application it would be normal to get an error if sub-object doesn't exist. I have so added the sub-objects in the before method but it is really tedious ...

Comment: if it is so tedious, you should extract required data in a DBunit dataset and inject this dataset before you call your tested method. If you have many rows to fetch, you can even use a DBunit helper class to initialize them. I have just edited my answer to show a simple example  by using the official doc.